# Printing a binary tree in 2 dimensions using array in C

Tags: arrays, c, binary-tree

I am trying to implement a binary tree using unidimensional arrays. I understand the left node of a parent will be 2n+1 while the right node will be 2n+2, where n is the index of the parent. However, I cannot understand how I can use this information to print the binary tree in 2D. Essentially, I want to print it something like this:

```
      4
  2
      5
1
      6
  3
      7
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of (pseudo-code)

```
PrintNode(0, 0);
```

and then

```
void PrintNode(int nodeIndex, int level)
{
  if (a[nodeIndex] != -1)
  {
      PrintNode(nodeIndex*2+1, level + 1);

      PrintSpaces(level * 4);
      PrintValue(a[nodeIndex]);
      NewLine();

      PrintNode(nodeIndex*2+2, level + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say ```a[nodeIndex] != -1``` does it check if a node is empty or not?